# Como imprimo un elemento JSON

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto

Holaa, soy nuevo en este lenguaje y tuve la curiosidad de hacer algo distinto pero aun no me sale:

Lo que quiero es guardar mi nombre en una variable (alumno) y esa misma variable agregarla a un objeto JSON y así imprimir el elemento del JSON.

Cuando lo imprimo me aparece **NaN**
Asi esta mi codigo:

```
let curso = {
  titulo: 'Curso de JS',
  duracion: 3.5,
  bloque: ['Nivel 1', 'Nivel intermedio', 'Profesional'],
  inscripcion: function(){
    console.log(alumno.nombreCompleto());
  }
}

let alumno = {
  nombre: "Orlando",
  apellido: 'Montes',
  nombreCompleto: ()=>{
    return (this.nombre + this.apellido);
}
}

curso.inscripcion();
```

Gracias:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) (`() => {}`) no crean el contexto del `this` como lo hacen las funciones normales (`function name() {}`). Las funciones flecha utilizan el valor del contexto de ejecución que la contiene.

Cuando una función flecha se define en una clase el `this` hace referencia a la instancia creada con el operdador `new`, sino hacen referencia al objeto `window` en el navegador y `global` en nodejs.

Para resolver tu error tienes que usar una función normal para que el `this` haga referencia al objeto actual.

```js
let curso = {
  titulo: 'Curso de JS',
  duracion: 3.5,
  bloque: ['Nivel 1', 'Nivel intermedio', 'Profesional'],
  inscripcion: function() {
    console.log(alumno.nombreCompleto());
  }
}

let alumno = {
  nombre: "Orlando",
  apellido: 'Montes',
  nombreCompleto: function() {
    return (this.nombre + ' ' + this.apellido);
}
}

curso.inscripcion();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación:)

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes cambiar el "this" por el nombre del json que estás llamando, de esta forma:

```js
let curso = {
  titulo: 'Curso de JS',
  duracion: 3.5,
  bloque: ['Nivel 1', 'Nivel intermedio', 'Profesional'],
  inscripcion: function(){
    console.log(alumno.nombreCompleto());
  }
}

let alumno = {
  nombre: "Orlando",
  apellido: 'Montes',
  nombreCompleto: () => {
    return (alumno.nombre + ' ' + alumno.apellido);
  }
}

curso.inscripcion();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, también me sirvió